# Excel : how sequential analysis and incremental counting? formula or macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

i would like to know if there is a way to analysis occurrence of words in a column in a sequential way. it is little bit complicate so here an example i would like to achieve:

here below is my colomn of two words "win" and "loose" that randomly alternate . lets say these are result of , for example, connect 4 game's sets, where the winner of the match, is the one who reach first 3 won sets.
The Goal would be to find a macro or a formula that could automatise the input of "victory" and "defeat" next to the line level where it happen.
I guess that the logic would be to count how many "win" and "loose" appear in sequential order from top to bottom. Then reset the count as soon the "win" count or the "loose" reach first a total of 3. without forgetting to either write "victory" or "defeat" depending on wich one reached 3 firstly.... or maybe more simple: just increment of bottom total count as seen in my exemple

SET   **= MATCHES**

win

loose

win

win    **= victory**

win

win

win     **= victory**

loose

loose

win

loose     **= defeat**

win

win

win        **= victory**

loose

win

win

loose

loose       **= defeat**

**total results of matches :** victory: 3 / defeats : 2

is it possible to achieve that in excel ?

thank you so much

windows 10 - excel 2016 - beginner level

**ps : here is additional infos:**

- the "victory" and "defeat" i input was just here to clarify the sequential counting that is needed.

So mostly i would like the formula to sequentially analyse the colomn A1-A19 starting by A1 and counting how many "WIN" and "LOOSE" , stopping as soon as one of the two reached 3 .

exemple :
if 3x "WON" is reached before 3x "LOOSE" in the sequential counting (whether it could be 3x WON vs 0,1 or 2x LOOSE) then increment the "victory" by +1 (it would be perfect to be able to input the word "victory" or "defeat" next to the level where a match is won or lost but it is not mandatory as it could be too complicate).

Then put back counting to 0 in order start counting again for the next following match , if for exemple this time the counting sees "LOOSE" reaching 3 before "WIN" made it (again whatever WON reached 0 or 1 or 2 , the important is the first reaching 3) then increment the block "defeat" by +1.
then having back the counting to 0 in order to continue the counting of the following sets

In the hope it can helps

Answer (score 0):

Try the following macro

```vba
Sub GetResults()

    Dim x, y As Integer 'Counter for win/loss
    Dim lastrow As Long

    'Get last row with value of column A
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Loop through the values
    For i = 1 To lastrow

        If Range("A" & i).Value = "win" Then
            x = x + 1
        Else
            y = y + 1
        End If


        If x = 3 Then
            Range("B" & i) = "Victory"
            x = 0
            y = 0
        End If

        If y = 3 Then
            Range("B" & i) = "Defeat"
            x = 0
            y = 0
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```